# Checking errors in my program

Tags: input, counter

I'm trying to make some changes to my dictionary counter in python. I want make some changes to my current counter, but not making any progress so far. I want my code to show the number of different words.

This is what I have so far:

```
# import sys module in order to access command line arguments later
import sys


# create an empty dictionary
dicWordCount = {}

# read all words from the file and put them into 
#'dicWordCount' one by one,
# then count the occurance of each word
```

Comment: don't change code in question. Now you have nothing.

Comment: Exactly, That's why it's downvoted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a work request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your first problem, add a variable for the word count and one for the different words. So `wordCount = 0` and `differentWords = 0`. In the loop for your file reading put `wordCount += 1` at the top, and in your first if statement put `differentWords += 1`. You can print these variables out at the end of the program as well.

The second problem, in your printing, add the if statement, `if len(strKey)>4:`.

If you want a full example code here it is.

```
import sys

fileSource = open(sys.argv[1], "rt")
dicWordCount = {}
wordCount = 0
differentWords = 0

for strWord in fileSource.read().split():
  wordCount += 1
  if strWord not in dicWordCount:
    dicWordCount[strWord] = 1
    differentWords += 1
  else:
    dicWordCount[strWord] += 1

for strKey in sorted(dicWordCount, key=dicWordCount.get, reverse=True):
  if len(strKey) > 4: # if the words length is greater than four.
    print(strKey, dicWordCount[strKey])
print("Total words: %s\nDifferent Words: %s" % (wordCount, differentWords))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Count function from collections lib:

```
from collections import Counter
q = Counter(fileSource.read().split())
total = sum(q.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first qs, you can use `set` to help you count the number of different words. (Assume there is a space between every two words)

```
str = 'apple boy cat dog elephant fox'
different_word_count = len(set(str.split(' ')))
```

For your second qs, using a dictionary to help you record the word_count is ok.

Comment: thank you! Can you please write a full answer and I will accept it? I'm just getting started on python. Where should I add the str = 'apple boy cat dog elephant fox'
different_word_count = len(set(str.split(' '))) ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
#gives unique words count
unique_words = len(dicWordCount)


total_words = 0
for k, v in dicWordCount.items():
    total_words += v

#gives total word count
print(total_words)
```

You don't need a separate variable for counting word counts since you're using dictionary, and to count the total words, you just need to add the values of the keys(which are just counts)